# User page questions list layout bug

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, question-lists, activity-tab

[image]

"Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" displaces way too much horizontal space on the left side.

Comment: Broswer and version?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Chrome 68

Comment: What's the point of telling that?

Comment: @AlexL The browser and version? Because the issue might not be reproducible in all browsers or in all versions.

Comment: Also in Firefox 61.0.1(64-bit)

Comment: Just ran into this myself. It's weird.

Comment: This is happening for me, still, Chrome 73